# Does any competition currently give solid gold medals to winners?

Tags: trivia, international-sports, awards

I read from some sources that the dream of every sportsman, the Olympic Gold Medal, is not 100% pure gold. ([Olympic Gold medals are required to be made from at least 92.5% silver, and must contain a minimum of 6 grams of gold](http://history1900s.about.com/od/greateventsofthecentury/a/olympicfacts.htm)).

> The last series of Olympic medals to be made of solid gold were awarded at the 1912 Olympic Games in Stockholm, Sweden.

Do any of the present sports competitions give pure solid gold medals for the winners?

Comment: Are you asking if any sport *currently* awards solid gold medals, or are you asking if any sport has ever awarded solid gold in the past?

Comment: Present,to be more clear 'active' Competitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, some sports competitions still give out solid gold awards to the winners.

According to Wikipedia, the Kentucky Derby awards the [only solid gold trophy in sports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kentucky_Derby_Trophy).

Professional sports championship rings (such as [Super Bowl rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_ring), [World Series rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Series_ring), and [NBA championship rings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Championship_ring)), are usually solid gold.

Championship belts are usually gold plated. However, there are occasionally solid gold championship belts made for special events, such as the 2013 WBC Mayweather vs. Alvarez belt and the 2015 WBC Mayweather vs Pacquiao belt ([source](http://www.totalsportek.com/boxing/most-expensive-belt-for-winner-of-pacquiao-vs-mayweather-fight/)).

To be clear, although these examples are *solid* gold, they are not always *pure* 24K gold; they may be a lesser purity number.